# Can't Resize Ext4 Partition through Gparted on Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, gparted, ext4

I would like to increase my Linux Mint partition (/dev/sda3) with Gparted through a live Ubuntu session. However, Gparted doesn't increase my Linux Mint partition even though it's not mounted and has swap off. I can increase my Windows partition (/dev/sda1) which is formatted as ntfs through Gparted. Is it possible to resize the Linux Mint partition through Gparted or will I need to use terminal commands?

[Picture of my Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRokj.png)

[Picture showing that /dev/sda3 can't be resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjTbZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'd be increasing the partition using some "empty" space on your partition? If you are resizing your windows partition, and it's right beside a linux one (/ or /home), you'd be in essence "moving" the start of that linux partition, could cause some headaches. Not unfixable headaches, but headaches nonetheless.

Comment: No I want to use the unallocated space (19.53 gigabytes) and increase the linux partition.

Comment: Nonetheless, you need to resize that partition from a live session, with that partition not mounted via fstab , etc. A mounted system can't be resized.

Comment: I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS live session and have /dev/sda3 unmounted [link](https://imgur.com/a/vIrM4), but I still can't resize it.

Comment: This sounds like what you are wanting to do: <a href="https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=931228">

Answer (score 0):

Following is a quote from the GParted Manual that explains why partition sda3 cannot be increased in size:

> To grow or move a partition, unallocated space must be available adjacent to the partition.
>
> If you are growing a logical partition, then the unallocated space must be within the extended partition.
>
> If you are growing a primary partition, then the unallocated space must not be within the extended partition.
>
> You can move unallocated space to be inside or outside of the extended partition by resizing the extended partition boundaries.

For more details see [GParted Manual - Resizing a Partition](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition).

Note that if you move the start of a partition then as mentioned in the other answer you may need to restore the ability to boot.  This is also described in the [GParted Manual - Moving a Partition](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition).